# Horizontal menu using css transform on hover

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a pull out navigation where the user hovers over the "Menu" handle and it pulls out. I'm having success doing so coming from the top, but I want the boxes to be stacked horizontally and coming from the left side, moving right.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            nav {
                position:absolute;
                top:-190px;
            }

            .menu:hover {
                -webkit-transform:translate(0px,190px);
                -moz-transform:translate(0px,190px);
                -o-transform:translate(0px,190px);
                -ms-transform:translate(0px,190px);
                transform:translate(0px,190px);
                -webkit-transition:ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:ease-in-out;
                -o-transition:ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition:ease-in-out;
                transition:ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
                -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
                -o-transition-duration: .5s;
                -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
                transition-duration: .5s;
            }

            div {
                width:40px;
                height:40px;
                background-color:#999999;
                border:black solid 2px;
                padding:2px;
                font-family:Helvetica;
                font-size:.8em;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                margin:1px;
            }

            .handle {
                border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
            }

            div:hover {
                background-color:#009999;
                border:black solid 2px;
                -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
                -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
                -o-transform: translateX(10px);
                -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
                tranform: translateX(10px);
            }

            div:active {
                background-color:#006699;
                border:black solid 2px;
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
                -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
                -o-transform: translateX(-10px);
                -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
                tranform: translateX(-10px);
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href"http://www.lvc.edu/" target="_new"><div> <p>Link 1</p></div></a>
            <a href"http://www.lvc.edu/" target="_new"><div> <p>Link 2</p></div></a>
            <a href"http://www.lvc.edu/" target="_new"><div> <p>Link 3</p></div></a>
            <a href"http://www.lvc.edu/" target="_new"><div> <p>Link 4</p></div></a>
            <div class="handle"><p>Menu</p></div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

My main issue isn't the actual animation (I'm pretty sure I know how to figure it out), it's more the location of the boxes and how I'd rather them be horizontal instead of stacked.

Sorry if this was confusing, hopefully you guys understand!

Comment: So you want a horizontal menu sliding in from the left?

Comment: Yes, a horizontal menu sliding from the left.

Answer (score 1):

To get a horizontal menu, follow one of the innumeral tutorials around the web, for example this one:

http://jamesowers.co.uk/css-tutorials/50/horizontal-css-list-menu/

(it is customary to use unordered lists for menu alternatives)

To make it slide in from the left, you would have to change the starting position offset to left:

```
nav { position:absolute; left: [negative number corresponding to the width of the menu];}
```

And for the sliding:

```
.menu:hover {
    ...
    transform:translate([width of menu],0);
    ...
}
```

***Please note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not support css transform, which would mean that the menu wouldn't be accessible (excluding everyone still using IE under Windows XP). Perhaps you could consider using JavaScript/jQuery instead?***